# Variables in loops Dont Work, Batch

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file

This is the new Script and it Still Doesn't Work
I Get `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
on `FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "C:\Windows\System32\tasks\at!num! ^| FIND "Command"`) DO (`

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set num=1
:START
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Windows\System32\tasks\at%num%" (GOTO:EOF)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "C:\Windows\System32\tasks\at!num! ^| FIND "Command"`) DO (
 set var=%%A
 ECHO %var%
 SET /a num=%num%+1
 PAUSE
)
GOTO:START
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand your code, I'm going to break it down into logic first then try to solve it. Let me know if I miss a detail...

```
Set num var to 0 
Begin :Loop 
set num var to its current value  ::NOT NEEDED - You've specified this prior to the GOTO 
increment num var by +1 
if myfolder\at* file exists then read at%num% and find a string then output that line to %tmp%\1.txt ::Need quotations on file location. 
set F var to the line stored in %tmp%\1.txt 
set F="%%F: =%%" ::Please explain what you are trying to do with this command. 
set F to start on 10th character and remove the last 11 characters from the line. 
echo the variable 
If it doesn't exist, exit, but if it does return to :Loop
```

You should tell us what you are attempting. If it is as simple as saving a variable from a text file output, `set F=<file.txt` will work. If it didn't, then something happened prior to that command. Still... what is `set F="%%F: =%%"`?

Unless you are using a FOR loop variable, there is no need to use %% on each end of the variable.

If this were a FOR loop, it would look like this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set num=1
:START
IF NOT EXIST "myFolder\at%num%.txt" (GOTO:EOF)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "myFolder\at%num%.txt" ^| FIND /i "string"`) DO (
  PAUSE
  SET var=%%A
  ECHO !var!
  PAUSE
  SET var=!var: =!
  ECHO !var!
  PAUSE
  SET var=!var:~10,-11!
  ECHO !var!
  PAUSE
  SET /a num=!num!+1
  ECHO !num!
  PAUSE
 )
 GOTO:START
```

One good practice to check if commands are working, such as SET, insert an ECHO on the variable and a PAUSE right after each time you believe the variable should be changed. This will track what has changed on the variable so you can see if your command was correct and the changes were made.

Comment: `set F="%%F: =%%"`
Supposed to Delete whitespace from the text

Comment: I checked your script and I got a syntax error
On
`IF NOT EXIST "C: \ Windows \ System32 \ Tasks \ at! Num!" (GOTO: EOF)`

Comment: My mistake it is failing in `FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`TYPE "myFolder\at!num! ^| FIND "<Command>"`) DO (`

Comment: Fully editing my FOR loop script. In my answer. Tested it and it works. Try it yourself.

Comment: I solved my problem using a different method But really thank you for your help (I checked and indeed your script now works)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Batch's inbuilt function for loops, see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

```
Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers

Syntax   
      FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

Or maybe [iterating over files](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) in a folder would be better for what you are trying to do?

```
Loop through files (Recurse subfolders)

Syntax
      FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command
```

Or [iterating over file contents](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)?

```
Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform
a command against each item.

Syntax
    FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 

    FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command
```

This site has plenty of examples [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) which should point you in the right direction.

There are a few issues with your code, I've amended as follows to get the variable populated with the contents of the temp file.

```
set num=0
:Loop
    set /a num=%num%+1
    if exist "myFolder\at*" (
    TYPE "myFolder\at%num%" | FINDSTR "\<Command\>" > "%temp%\1.txt"
    set /P F=<"%TEMP%\1.txt"
    Echo %F%
    Pause
)
```

Comment: My problem is actually not increasing the numbers it works pretty good ..
The problem is putting the content of %TEMP%\1.txt into a Variable and Perform some changes to the information thet is now stored in the Variable

Comment: I guess I'm suggesting the for loop approach would give you a path as a variable. However, which bit in your code isn't working?

Comment: `set /P F=<%TEMP%\1.txt
    set F="%%F: =%%"
    set F=%%F:~10,-11%%
    Echo %%F%% `

Comment: So you want to prompt the user to enter a string, (`set /P F=<%TEMP%\1.txt`)? It would help you know more about what you are doing.

Comment: No what I'm trying to do is to store the contents of the file into a variable and then Perform some changes to the information thet is now stored in the Variable the `set /P F=<` Supposed to do it but in the loop it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but have you tried enabling:

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Then, inside the loop (or the `IF(...)`), you use `!foo!` to signify environment variables instead of `%foo%`.

See `setlocal /?` and `set /?` for more information.